# ¿Por qué no aparece la foto?

Tags: html, imagen

Tengo 2 fotos, una sí, me aparece, y la otra no, y no entiendo cuál es el problema si el código es el mismo.

Código:

```
<body>
  <?php include'BarraDCabecera.php'; ?>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="float:right; width: 35rem;">
          <h4 class="card-title">Xperia 5</h4>
          <img class="card-img-top" src="/imagenes/xperia.jpg">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Cámara con tres objetivos</br>
              Autoenfoque de ojos </br>
              Pantalla OLED FHD+ HDR de 21:9 </br>
              Plataforma móvil Qualcomm® Snapdragon™ 855 </br>
              DIMENSIONES 158 × 68 × 8,2 mm </br>
              PESO 164 g </br>
              RESISTENTE AL AGUA (IP65/68) </br>
              Doble SIM </br>
              Batería 3140 mAh</p>
            <p> Precio 700€ </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="float: left; width: 35rem;">
          <h4 class="card-title">Galaxy Z Flip</h4>
          <img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/galaxy.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100"></div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
      <div class="col">Column</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

La del *Xperia* no sale, he probado 10 fotos ya, y cambiarle el nombre otras 10 veces por cada foto, y no hay manera.

Comment: En la etiqueta img de la imagen de xperia, en el src tienes un slash delante de imagenes( "/imagenes/xperia.jpg"), prueba a cambiarlo por "imagenes/xperia.jpg".

Comment: vaya cagada la barra  jaja

Answer (score 8, accepted):

al cargar la foto de xperia lo haces

```
/imagenes/xperia.jpg
```

mientras que para la de Samsung..

```
imagenes/galaxy.jpg
```

Prueba a quitar la barra

Answer (score 5):

Prueba a quitar la barra en el otro también. Así:
Este es el bueno:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/galaxy.jpg"alt="Card image cap">
```

El que está mal corregido:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="imagenes/xperia.jpg">
```

Si aún así no se ve comprueba que la imagen sea .jpg y no .png o .jpeg

Answer (score 5):

Posibles soluciones:

```
src="/imagenes/xperia.jpg"
```

lo cambias por:

```
src="./imagenes/xperia.jpg"
```

o

```
src="imagenes/xperia.jpg"
```

¿Aun no se ve? Comprueba que:

1. Existe la imagen en la ubicación específica. Y que indicas correctamente esta ubicación, si imágenes esta por ejemplo dentro de `public/` ya la tienes mal (a no ser que tu HTML también este en esta carpeta).
2. La extensión de la imagen es la correcta, ya sea `.jpg` o `.jpeg` (no es lo mismo).